# Stop datatemplates from being inherited in nested contentpresenters

Tags: c#, wpf, contentpresenter

I use a range of viewmodel classes in my application to represent the data. I define 2 or more "ViewPresenter" controls (based on the ContentPresenter) to show these viewmodels in for instance "minimal", "summary" or "detail" modes. Each of the presenter classes use a resourcedictionary to define the datatemplates for all the viewmodels it needs to be able to show.

Now here's the problem: When different types of these viewpresenters are contained within each other, they inherit datatemplates from their containers, which leads to some issues. How can I stop that inheritance from happening?

Edit: Example for illustration

```
// first ContentPresenter
<ViewPresenter DataContext="{Binding DerivedObj}">
  <ViewPresenter.Resources>
    <DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DerivedClass}">
      <DerivedClassView>

        // Nested ContentPresenter
        <ViewPresenter DataContext="{BaseObj}">
           <ViewPresenter.Resources>
             <DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type BaseClass}"/>
           </ViewPresenter.Resources>
        </ViewPresenter>

      </DerivedClassView>
    <DataTemplate/>
  </ViewPresenter.Resources>
</ViewPresenter>
```

So the problem that occurs here is that the nested template is less specific than the one in the higher level contentpresenter, and so it is never shown. The nested contentpresenter needs to start with a clear resourcedictionary, and refrain from using the higher contentpresenter's datatemplates.

Comment: Try to not inherit style: `<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{x:Null}"/>`

Comment: @StepUp It's not the style that's being inherited, but the control's resources.

Comment: @ErikVerboom Can u post some pseudo code for more clarity

Comment: Looks to me as a good place to make use of `DataTemplateSelector`...

Comment: @Grx70 I hadn't heard of the DataTemplateSelector before, but looked into it after your comment. I'm not sure if it's the right fit yet, because it's a property of the presenter that determines the distinction in this case, not a property of the viewmodel.

Comment: The main idea here is that you create a class deriving from [`DataTemplateSelector`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx) and override the `SelecteTemplate` method, which takes the content (a view model) and the container (a `ViewPresenter`) as parameters. Then you can apply custom logic to return a `DataTemplate`. You can, for instance, check the view model type and look for appropriate template restricting only to the container's resource dictionary (thus ignoring "inherited" templates).

Comment: Yes you're right, that would work and is a solid solution to the problem. That being said, I would still be interested in finding out if it's possible to solve the problem as I posted it; ie how to stop the resources from streaming down automatically.

Comment: Regarding your question as stated, I'm not 100% sure, but I have a strong feeling that this is not possible. Not to mention doing so would have major consequences - e.g. all implicit styles would no longer apply, including those setting default templates for controls shipped with WPF, so you'd have to redefine/re-reference those each time you "cut off" inherited resources.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, I believe that settles it. If you add that as an answer, I will mark it as the correct one.